# How to solve Windows Azure Diagnostic Runtime Error (Could not create WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=xx, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xx

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, c#-5.0

```
privateLibManager libManager;
private LibManager Connect()
{
   this.libManager=new LibManager();//here we are getting an error
}
```

**Error:**

The type initializer for 'SWConfigDataClientLib.LibManager' threw an exception

**Inner Exception:**

Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener,     Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics,Version=2.2.0.0,Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

**Source**

IpPbxCDSClientLib

Answer (score 15):

First make sure you have added references to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics` from the SDK folders (typically c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.2\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll)

Next, if you are not running your project in the emulator (i.e. the cloud project set as the startup project), then set the trace filter level to `TraceEventType.Error` or `TraceEventType.None` to avoid trying to write verbose Azure messages to the trace listener.  In you web or app config:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter level="TraceEventType.Error" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not work for me. In fact in VS2013 with Azure SDK 2.3 the syntax highlighter indicates that "The 'level' attribute is not allowed" in the <filter> element.

Comment: I get "The 'level' attribute is not allowed" and then it throws an exception for that error

Comment: It should be `type`, not `level`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.

I was missing a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics

Answer (score 2):

Ok So even I had this exception being thrown continuously. However, my case was a little different.

I wanted to get rid of this reference as it was no longer required in the project. So I removed it from the references. But while running the application, I started getting this exception at a `Debug.WriteLine(...);` statement which suggested that the reference was required.

On further analysis, I found that the below section was present in the project's `app.config` file which was the cause of the exception.

```
<trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
```

After removing the reference AND also removing the above section from config file, the issue got fixed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added this reference to your project
**Microsoft.Azure.Plugins.Diagnostics.dll**